# Seleccionar elemento hijo jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, this

Tengo una sección de la página donde constan diferentes menús en modo tarjeta, al hacer click en el botón se muestra el código del menú para ser canjeado.

La cara que se muestra del menú es el `div` con clase `menu_back_no`.
He desarrollado un código JS que controla el evento del botón y cuando se hace `click`, esta clase cambia a `menu_back_si` y se muestra otra cara de la tarjeta del menú. El botón que controla es el boyon con clase `codigo`.

Todo funciona correctamente pero el problema es que no puedo detectar el menú exacto donde estoy actuando, es decir, mi página consta de 6 menús. Cuando hago click, actúa sobre todos y no sobre el que estoy haciendo click.

Lo que quiero es que solo actúa en el elemento donde estoy haciendo click y no en todos, he probado con `$(this)` pero me recoge el elemento botón y no el elemento padre.

Les adjunto el código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").on("click", ".codigo", (function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        
        if($(".menu section").hasClass("menu_back_no")){
            console.log("Estoy dentro");

            $(".menu section").removeClass();
        }

        if(!$(".menu section").hasClass("menu_back_si")){
            $(".menu section").addClass("menu_back_si");
        }
    }));
})
```

```css
.menu_back_si{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.cod_num{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 48px;
    color: #6666cc;
    width: 200px;
}

.cod_info{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #272727;
    margin-top: 100px !important;
    margin-bottom: 100px !important;
}

.codigo_back{
    height: 30px;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #dfdd4b !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;}

.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition-property: color;
    transition-property: color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #6666cc;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
    transform-origin: 50%;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover, 
.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus, 
.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active {
    color: white;
}
.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover:before, 
.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus:before, 
.codigo_back.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* -- -- -- (Fin) Animación carta -- -- -- */


.menu{
    margin: 0 60px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 25px 22px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu *{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu_img{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.menu_precio{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #dfdd4b;

}

.menu_info{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.botones{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.botones a{
    height: 30px;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #dfdd4b !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.botones a img{
    height: 20px;
}

.botones a.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition-property: color;
    transition-property: color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.botones a.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #6666cc;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
    transform-origin: 50%;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.botones a.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active {
    color: white;
}
.botones a.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover:before, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus:before, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
        <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- CDN Bootstrap-->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="menus_carta">

                        <div class="row row-eq-height">

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                <div class="menu">

                                    <div class="menu_img">
                                        <img src="images/menu1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                    </div>

                                    <p class="menu_precio">10,00€</p>
                                    <div class="menu_info">
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Hamburguesa carne vacuno, 
                                            lechuga, tomate queso cheddar 
                                            y salsa secreta
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Papas fritas
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Coca cola 300ml
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="botones centrado">

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="#" role="button">
                                            <img src="images/corazon.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo" href="#" role="button">Ver código</a>


                                    </div>

                                    <section class="menu_back_no animacion">

                                        <p class="cod_num">COD #4567</p>
                                        <p class="cod_info">
                                            Presenta este código en caja y 
                                            agilizaremos tu pedido
                                        </p>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo_back" href="#" role="button">Volver</a>
                                    </section>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                <div class="menu">

                                    <div class="menu_img">
                                        <img src="images/menu1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                    </div>

                                    <p class="menu_precio">10,00€</p>
                                    <div class="menu_info">
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Hamburguesa carne vacuno, 
                                            lechuga, tomate queso cheddar 
                                            y salsa secreta
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Papas fritas
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Coca cola 300ml
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="botones centrado">

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="#" role="button">
                                            <img src="images/corazon.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo" href="#" role="button">Ver código</a>


                                    </div>

                                    <section class="menu_back_no animacion">

                                        <p class="cod_num">COD #4567</p>
                                        <p class="cod_info">
                                            Presenta este código en caja y 
                                            agilizaremos tu pedido
                                        </p>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo_back" href="#" role="button">Volver</a>
                                    </section>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-sm col-xs-12">

                                <div class="menu">

                                    <div class="menu_img">
                                        <img src="images/menu1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                    </div>

                                    <p class="menu_precio">10,00€</p>
                                    <div class="menu_info">
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Hamburguesa carne vacuno, 
                                            lechuga, tomate queso cheddar 
                                            y salsa secreta
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Papas fritas
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Coca cola 300ml
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="botones centrado">

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="#" role="button">
                                            <img src="images/corazon.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo" href="#" role="button">Ver código</a>


                                    </div>

                                    <section class="menu_back_no animacion">

                                        <p class="cod_num">COD #4567</p>
                                        <p class="cod_info">
                                            Presenta este código en caja y 
                                            agilizaremos tu pedido
                                        </p>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo_back" href="#" role="button">Volver</a>
                                    </section>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="separa-100"></div>

                        <div class="row row-eq-height">

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                <div class="menu">

                                    <div class="menu_img">
                                        <img src="images/menu1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                    </div>

                                    <p class="menu_precio">10,00€</p>
                                    <div class="menu_info">
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Hamburguesa carne vacuno, 
                                            lechuga, tomate queso cheddar 
                                            y salsa secreta
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Papas fritas
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Coca cola 300ml
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="botones centrado">

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="#" role="button">
                                            <img src="images/corazon.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo" href="#" role="button">Ver código</a>

                                    </div>


                                    <section class="menu_back_no animacion">

                                        <p class="cod_num">COD #4567</p>
                                        <p class="cod_info">
                                            Presenta este código en caja y 
                                            agilizaremos tu pedido
                                        </p>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo_back" href="#" role="button">Volver</a>
                                    </section>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                <div class="menu">

                                    <div class="menu_img">
                                        <img src="images/menu1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                    </div>

                                    <p class="menu_precio">10,00€</p>
                                    <div class="menu_info">
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Hamburguesa carne vacuno, 
                                            lechuga, tomate queso cheddar 
                                            y salsa secreta
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Papas fritas
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Coca cola 300ml
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="botones centrado">

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="#" role="button">
                                            <img src="images/corazon.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo" href="#" role="button">Ver código</a>


                                    </div>

                                    <section class="menu_back_no animacion">

                                        <p class="cod_num">COD #4567</p>
                                        <p class="cod_info">
                                            Presenta este código en caja y 
                                            agilizaremos tu pedido
                                        </p>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo_back" href="#" role="button">Volver</a>
                                    </section>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-sm col-xs-12">

                                <div class="menu">

                                    <div class="menu_img">
                                        <img src="images/menu1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                    </div>

                                    <p class="menu_precio">10,00€</p>
                                    <div class="menu_info">
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Hamburguesa carne vacuno, 
                                            lechuga, tomate queso cheddar 
                                            y salsa secreta
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Papas fritas
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="menu_elem">
                                            Coca cola 300ml
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="botones centrado">

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="#" role="button">
                                            <img src="images/corazon.svg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo" href="#" role="button">Ver código</a>


                                    </div>

                                    <section class="menu_back_no animacion">

                                        <p class="cod_num">COD #4567</p>
                                        <p class="cod_info">
                                            Presenta este código en caja y 
                                            agilizaremos tu pedido
                                        </p>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-shutter-out-horizontal codigo_back" href="#" role="button">Volver</a>
                                    </section>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                    </div>
```

Comment: En la demostración está sin configurar el botón de volver una vez se muestra el código, pero no es problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el problema utilizando la función `each` para cada elemento `menu` y dentro controlar el click en el botón. Adjunto código para curiosos

```
    $(".menu").each(function(){

        var menu = $(this);
        $(menu).on("click", ".codigo", (function(event){

            console.log($(this));
            event.preventDefault();

            if($("section", menu).hasClass("menu_back_no")){
                console.log("Estoy dentro");

                $("section", menu).removeClass();
            }

            if(!$("section", menu).hasClass("menu_back_si")){
                $("section", menu).addClass("menu_back_si");
            }
        }));
    });

});
```